# Measures in a Column

Tags: matrix, powerbi, dax, measure

I have 4 measures in Power BI that return a date. I want to show it in the power bi matrix as if it were a column. What I can do?.
The matrix already has rows and values ​​but I need the dates of these measures to behave as a column to be able to bring the values ​​of each date.

[image]

Comment: You would have to create calculated columns to do that. You can't put a measure on an axis. You could then use a Parameter to let the user choose which of the 4 columns to display on the X-axis.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible to derive scalar values from measures that may not be visible as columns in a power bi matrix.